# Issue with pygame set_alpha() setting image transparency

Tags: python, pygame, set, alpha

Aohoj,

in Pygame I'm trying to set the transparency of an image.
I use this:

```
ship = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(DIR, "spaceship.png"))
ship.set_alpha(128)
```

Problem:
the code works on Mx Linux but does not work on the Raspberry Pi (Raspbian Linux).
How to solve this? Could there be a problem with the Pygame version?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? no effect? exception?

Comment: No effect. Image is not transparenci. I have found, that my Mx Linux has Pygame ver.2.0.1 but Raspbian only Pygame ver. 1.9.4

Answer (score 0):

A PNG file generates a *Surface* with an format that supports per pixel alpha.  The combination of  [`set_alpha`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_alpha) with such a format has been supported since Pygame 2.0. Before you had to choose either `set_alpha()` or alpha per pixel. See [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_alpha)

> This value is different than the per pixel Surface alpha. For a surface with per pixel alpha, blanket alpha is ignored and None is returned.
>
> Changed in pygame 2.0: per-surface alpha can be combined with per-pixel alpha.

---

If you want to smoothly fade in or out an image, write a function that "blends" an image with the screen. In the following function `BlendSurface`, the parameter `alpha` is the opacity value of the surface in range[0.0, 1.0]. 0.0 would generate a completely transparent (invisible) surface. 1.0 would generate a completely opaque surface:

```py
def BlendSurface(surf, pos, alpha):
    surf.set_alpha(min(int(alpha*255), 255))
    screen.blit(surf, pos)
```

See also [Pygame : smooth picture aparition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593653/pygame-smooth-picture-aparition/54594196#54594196).

Comment: Yea. Issue maybe solved. I have different Pygame version. 2.0.1 vs. 1.9.4. I am looking for update solving.